# replace \ is not working in ADF set variable

Tags: variables, replace, azure-data-factory

How to replace \ in ADF pipeline. Where ever I am using double quotes it is \ by default and to remove it I used replace function but it is also not working.

TIA

Comment: could you please provide sample input and output?

Comment: You need to update the code along with the question.Otherwise how others can help you

Answer (score 0):

> Where ever I am using double quotes it is \ by default

[image]

Yes, ADF by default adds the `\` for the `"` because it works as an escape character in ADF.

You cannot remove or replace it from the above string variable as its not part of the string. It only shows when you display variable in ADF. When you use that variable that won't affect your variable variable operations.

**`str1` length:**

[image]

**Normal string `"Rakesh"` length:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

You can see when I check the length of the above string `str1` and normal string `"Rakesh"` in integer variables, it is same. So, there is no need to remove or replace the `\`, you can use your variables as it is.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your detailed explanation. I am trying to call a command in ADF parameter and that command is getting failed because of \ in it. Same command is running fine If I call it directly(in that case command is not having any \)

Comment: Can you provide your command in ADF parameter along with your pipeline image? what error it is giving?

Comment: "value": "cmd.1\": \"dbt --log-format json run-operation --profiles-dir $DBT_MODEL_PATH --target $SF_DBT_TARGET --threads 4 --profile $SF_DBT_PROFILE DBT_MACRO"

This is the command and here I need to remove \ from this whole string

Comment: Ok your command itself has `\` and you wanna replace it right? If the command in parameter or variable, use the expression like this to achieve your requirement. @replace(<command_parameter>,'\',''). Even the command is hard coded or stored in variable, it will work.

Comment: I tried it's not working in adf pipeline

Comment: Is there any other way to replace \ in ADF pipeline or to call command inside pipeline parameter, so that it will not append \ before "